# New to Ruby: Defining Methods

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec

I'm trying to teach myself Ruby. I don't know anyone who knows it, so I don't have anyone to help with my very simple, perhaps annoying problems. I'm running the following code and getting the following error:

```
def simon_says (command)
def echo (param)
    puts "#{param}" 
end
end
```

The error:

```
PS R:\learn_ruby\03_simon_says> rake
(in R:/learn_ruby)
You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/) to use colour on Windows

Simon says
  echo
     should echo hello (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Simon says echo should echo hello
 Failure/Error: echo("hello").should == "hello"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `echo' for #RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x2fb5690>
 # ./03_simon_says/simon_says_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.003 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

The Rspec code can be found here (Github): [simon_says_spec.rb](https://github.com/Protosac/learn_ruby/blob/master/03_simon_says/simon_says_spec.rb)

I just really have no idea what's wrong. Why would it say 'echo' is undefined? It looks defined to me. I also tried just outputting "hello" itself instead of the method parameter (param). Same error. All help appreciated. Also, if anyone knows of a more level appropriate place I can get this kind of help, it'd be nice.

Comment: what is simon_says ? It is class or method.

Comment: The instructions make it seem that is supposed to be a method. I tried running it as a class with no luck. I'm supposed to be practicing functions, strings and default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program says the following:

> Define a method called `simon_says`. When that function is executed, it should define a method called `echo`.

Thus, before you invoke `simon_says()`, `echo` does not exist:

```
echo("foo")
# NoMethodError
simon_says("whatever")
# => nil
echo("bar")
# bar
# => nil
```

Now, I do not know *why* you wrapped `def echo` inside `def simon_says`, so I can't really offer any helpful advice as to what you *should* be doing instead of what you now are.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I greatly appreciate your effort. The instructions seem like I'm supposed to wrap a method in a method. I'm creating a method simon_says and its supposed to execute this list of commands (perhaps classes?). For example, echo is one of them. Calling simon_says should allow me to call other data from the method. or at least this was my understanding of it. I linked to the full instructions I have (the simon_says_spec on github link).

Comment: Also what you say doesnt quite make sense to me either. The error says define method simon_says and then have it define method echo. Is that not what my code does? wrap echo in simon_says? And why should it be wrapped the other way?

Comment: Normally, method definitions are not wrapped in other method definitions. Your spec only wants you to define a method `echo`. You do not have that. You have a method called `simon_says` which will define `echo` if it is ever called, which it isn't. For comparison, let's say you have a task of making a car. Instead, you make a car-making robot. That's a fail, you still don't have a car. Once you switch on a robot, you might have a car; but you might never switch it on, and then, no car for you. Make sense?

Comment: I found that you were right. Once I removed the first method simon_says everything worked from there. Whats confusing is that the instructions seemed to imply defining simon_says. While I fixed the spec, I don't understand why I didnt need to define simon_says. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your spec, I guess simon_says is class. It is not method. You are defining method inside method. Try this

```
class SimonSays
   def echo params
       puts "#{params}"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. But this does not work either. As mentioned above the only instructions I have for this are on the _spec.rb file linked from Github. What I need to be able to do is create a function called simon_says and nested in that function are various commands which do other things.

Comment: Looking at the spec, `simon_says` is a file (since the only place it is mentioned is a `require`. It is not a class, it is not a method.

Comment: @Amadan what is it then ??

Comment: "`simon_says` is a file" - can I be less clear than that? It means that your `def echo` is contained in `simon_says.rb`, in one of the directories specified by `$LOAD_PATH`. It is not wrapped in anything.